# How to use a GUID Collection var in GeneXus?

Tags: uniqueidentifier, genexus

I have a table (transaction) where I cache some data for my App. As I need an Identifier column created one with "GUID" datatype.

In my project I need to work with a collection of these Items.
So I declared the var **&SelectedGUIDs** of the type "**GUID**" with **Collection = TRUE**.

Items are added from the database into this collection, and the content is saved in a WebSession Var.
Then I try to recover the collection:

```
&SelectedGUIDs.fromXML('<Collection>  <item>ddfcee4b-3c3a-48db-b94d-4ad59c9b33b2</item>  <item>15b2a110-536c-49b5-a8c5-29389791d306</item>  <item>27199cc0-8785-42ab-9f66-3a6989c0efe2</item>  <item>0e706538-f503-431d-8b23-3511a793e2ed</item> </Collection>')
```

In this scenario, the command **&SelectedGUIDs.Count** would return 3 (correct!)

But the command **&myGUID = &SelectedGUIDs.Item(1)** causes the App to crash with the error: "**Specified cast is not valid.**" (&MyGUID is a GUID var)

Am I doing anything wrong?

(I could use a numeric sequencial identifier but rows are constantely being deleted and created in this table.)

Comment: I think the problem may be that the FromXML() is creating a collection of Strings instead of a collection of GUIDs. You can try loading the XML into a Strings collection and then convert each one to a GUID by using the FromString() method.

Comment: Well, it worked. It seems like a "workaround", but it works.
Thanks